# JS Jquery repeating a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple toggle function that I want to repeat 20+ times, is there a more elegant way of writing this without copy and pasting the same function and changing the numbers over and over?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$( ".p1" ).click(function() {
    $( ".c1" ).toggleClass("open");
    $( ".person" ).toggleClass("fadeout");
    $(this).removeClass('fadeout');
});

$( ".p2" ).click(function() {
    $( ".c2" ).toggleClass("open");
    $( ".person" ).toggleClass("fadeout");
    $(this).removeClass('fadeout');
});

$( ".p3" ).click(function() {
    $( ".c3" ).toggleClass("open");
    $( ".person" ).toggleClass("fadeout");
    $(this).removeClass('fadeout');
});
});
```

HTML for more context:

```
<div class="group">
 <div class="p1"></div>
 <div class="p2"></div>
 <div class="p3"></div>

 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c2"></div>
 <div class="c3"></div>
</div>

<div class="group">
 <div class="p4"></div>
 <div class="p5"></div>
 <div class="p6"></div>

 <div class="c4"></div>
 <div class="c5"></div>
 <div class="c6"></div>
</div>
```

This is for a profile page, when you click p1, then c1 opens, p2 then c2 opens, etc. I'm controlling the transitions with CSS

The solutions below worked but I've hit another issue. When p1, p2, etc is open all the other p's need to fadeout. Toggle seems to be creating some inconsistencies.

Comment: There is most likely a way to do this without ugly loops, as found in the answers below, but how you structure the DOM traversal logic would depend on the HTML. Could you edit the question to include a sample of it?

Comment: Give us some more context about how the ".p" classes and ".c" classes are structured in the DOM. Depending on this structure more efficient solution can be used.

Comment: Updated to give more context

Answer (score 2):

I guess a simple for-loop would do it!

```
for (let i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
  $( ".p" + i ).click(function() {
     $( ".c" + i ).toggleClass("open");
     $( ".person" ).toggleClass("fadeout");
     $(this).removeClass('fadeout');
  });
}
```

Comment: you did it first.. you should get the marks for it

Answer (score 0):

without html code, you could write a loop:

```
for(var i=1;i < 20; i++){
  $( ".p" + i ).click(function() {
    $( ".c" +i ).toggleClass("open");
    $( ".person" ).toggleClass("fadeout");
    $(this).removeClass('fadeout');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 for(let i = 1; i <= 20; i ++) {
    $( ".p" + i ).click(function() {
       $( ".c" + i ).toggleClass("open");
       $( ".person" ).toggleClass("fadeout");
       $(this).removeClass('fadeout');
    });
  }
});
```